# How to read a string line into double columns and save them in a method

Tags: java, arrays

I need to read the following line of string into separate columns with type of double and then save these columns in a method named `setPosition`. The string line is

```
[1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
```

which is stored in a file named `hh`.

I use the next code for doing this task but still have a problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); ++i){
    File file1 = new File("hh.txt");
           try {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(file1);
                while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line1 = scan.nextLine();
                   line1 = line1.replaceAll("\\[","");
                   line1 = line1.replaceAll("\\]","");
                  String[] columns = line1.split(",");
                double new_columns = Double.parseDouble(columns[i]);
                    setPosition(i, new_columns);
        }
           }
           catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

}
```

i got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at PSOFS.Swarm1.getParticle(Swarm1.java:39)
    at PSOFS.Main.main(Main.java:181)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: Where does `i` come from? Is it a loop variable of a loop that you haven't shown here?

Comment: the above error pointed out that the string line is not converted correctly to double columns which gives the index is 0 and the size is 0

Comment: sorry I forget the for loop. so I have edited the question.

Comment: There is no method `getParticle` in your code but your stacktrace includes it. What is line 39 of `Swarm1.java`?

Comment: this is another method in class swarm1..public Particle1 getParticle(int index) {
        return _swarm1.get(index);
    }

Comment: The error you give seems not related to the code the give, there is no link apparently, OR you forgot to gives the method's code

Comment: @sally reading the stack and you'r last comment i'd say that somewhere you'r accessing the _swarm1 list at index 0 before having added anything to it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the values in a `double[]` you just need to read once, and parse. Now you're reading in a loop, so you open an read the file multiple times for nothing

- open file and read content
- remove undesired chars, and split on comma
- parse each value do touble

Then you do whatever you want with the values

```
File file1 = new File("hh.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file1);
String[] values = scan.nextLine().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
double[] valuesD = new double[values.length];

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i){
    valuesD[i] = Double.parseDouble(values[i]);
}
```

[`>> Demo <<`](https://ideone.com/gTeiWY)